# add Single Value inside an existing Section in UITableView

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

i have a tableview with sections for adding section i created an `struct` :

```
 struct  datesStruct {
    var sectionYear : String!
    var sectionMonth : [String]!
}

 var datesStructArray = [datesStruct]()
```

now i want to add  a single value inside my exiting sections after checking if the section is satisfying my condition, any idea how am gonna do that ???

e.g. :

```
 if myTableViewSection1 == 2016{

 //add value  into this section 

 }
```

searched a lot about this but didn't get anything yet , if anybody knows then please do help me thanks

Comment: the optionals will make it pretty difficult

Comment: optionals  you mean `!` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put this function outside of your class (before "class" or after the last "}":

```
func == (leftItem: DatesStruct, rightItem: DatesStruct) -> Bool{
    return leftItem.sectionYear == rightItem.sectionYear
}
```

Then Use this:

```
struct DatesStruct: Equatable{
    var sectionYear : String!
    var sectionMonth : [String]!
}

var datesStructArray = [DatesStruct]()

func addMonthToYear(year: String, month: String){
    if let foundItem: DatesStruct = datesStructArray.filter({$0.sectionYear == year}).first {
        datesStructArray[datesStructArray.indexOf(foundItem)!].sectionMonth.append(month)
    }
}
```

Simply pass the year you're looking for and the month you want to add to addMonthToYear

Comment: Put the func == method outside of your class (update answer)

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/34z0sbd/9 can you see this please ? am getting an error `use of undeclaredType DatesStrcut` am i putted your code properly ?

Comment: Try putting your struct outside the class, before the == func. Ideally, the struct should be in it's own file and then it should work as well.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot , i rally appreciate this , was about to change my struct to class but you saved me next some hours thanks a lot

Comment: if you have a minute can you explain me what we are doing ?  are we finding the matching year (section) then adding value into that right ??

Comment: np! .filter is finding the DatesStruct that has the matching sectionYear, and then the passed month is being added to it's sectionMonth.

The func == is what allows the datesStruct to adhere to Equatable, which allows the indexOf function

gl!

Answer (score 1):

Declare an initializer

```
  struct  datesStruct {
        var sectionYear : String!
        var sectionMonth : [String]!

        init(sectionYear: String!, sectionMonth: [String]!) {
            self.sectionYear = sectionYear
            self.sectionMonth = sectionMonth
        }
    }

var datesStructArray = [datesStruct(sectionYear: "year", sectionMonth: ["month1", "month2"])]
```

Then check whether the `sectionMonth` contains desired string

Comment: FYI, structs have auto-gen init methods